# Correct association mapping in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Trying to change two relationships in our entity framework from many-to-one to many-to-many relationships. So I tried the obvious thing: clicked on each association on the diagram, changed the appropriate end of the association accordingly and then changed the name of the navigation property to a plural to reflect the change.

This lead to the following build error, or one each for the two changes I've made:

> Error 3002: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line
>   1761:Potential runtime violation of
>   table CustomerServices's keys
>   (CustomerServices.Id): Columns
>   (CustomerServices.Id) are mapped to
>   EntitySet
>   CompiledDatabaseCustomerService's
>   properties
>   (CompiledDatabaseCustomerService.CustomerService.Id)
>   on the conceptual side but they do not
>   form the EntitySet's key properties
>   (CompiledDatabaseCustomerService.CompiledDatabase.Id,
>   CompiledDatabaseCustomerService.CustomerService.Id)

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, so unsurprisngly I haven't had much luck fixing it. I've tried fiddling with the mapping details and adding referential constraints to no avail. Anyone point me in the right direction?

cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out all that's required is to update the database from the model. Idiot me - I thought that only regenerated the SQL scripts to create the database.

Comment: Ah. Haha...I hadn't even thought about this, but, yeah. No matter which way you go (either updating the database first, or updating the model first), you have to update the other. Makes sense! (And a good reminder for anybody who may run into this problem in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things to check when you get this error is to look and make sure that the key columns in your database schema match your entity definitions. I ran into a similar problem when I was doing an update.

If this doesn't appear to be your problem, then also check that you have not flipped the columns with respect to your mapping - make sure everything is mapping in the correct direction. (I would recommend looking at your mappings directly to see if this is what is happening.)

Comment: Thanks for looking. I haven't actually touched the key mappings, so that seems an unlikely source for the problem: all I've done is changed one end of an existing association. When you say to look at the mappings directly, do you mean to check the Designer.cs file?

Comment: @Matt - Take a look at the Table Mapping by right clicking on a table in your entity diagram and selecting "Table Mapping." Look under column mappings and make sure they are mapped appropriately. (BTW, I'm not positive my suggestions will help you (I hope they do), but those are two areas I have seen problems like this.)